# background-image not displayed if used also background-color

Tags: css, background, background-image, background-color

When I test it on various of browsers running locally (Apache on virtual server) - everything's fine, but once I upload it via FTP on a host - background-image does not get displayed if there's also set a background-color:

case no1:

```
body {
font-family: Candara, Tahoma, Verdana;
font-size: 0.9em;
color: white;
background: #242424 url("/Images/background.png") no-repeat top center;
}
```

case no2:

```
#top {
position: relative;
border-radius: 5px;
text-align: left;
background-color: #CC0000;
background-image: url("/Images/sky_banner.png");
background-position: top;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
height: 200px;
}

.top-content {
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
}
```

Once I remove the 'background-color' property, image gets displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This code...

```
element{
    background-image:url(background.png.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-color:#242424;
    background-position: top center;
}
```

Use background-color property after background-image

Comment: We have to load background image before background color.. ;)